# Datahandler (TCEmain) in cli_dispatch.phpsh (Extbase Command)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

is it possible to to use Datahander Scripts (TCEmain) in a Extbase Command Controller via cli_dispatch.phpsh? I tried but i got no result - no error message and no entry in the tables.

Perhaps there is no backend available in cli scripts ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the documentation for using DataHandler in CLI scripts [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/).

CLI scripts use the backend user `_cli_` (should be created automatically). You can take a look at the source of `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Console\CliRequestHandler::boot` if you're interested in how it works.

You can check the public instance variable `$dataHandler->errorLog` for any errors, DataHandler won't output anything else.

Mind that `cli_dispatch.phpsh` & Co. are deprecated, you can already use [Symfony Commands in TYPO3 CMS 8](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html).